# Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline

Tags: powershell

I'm new at writing in powershell but this is what I'm trying to accomplish.

1. I want to compare the dates of the two excel files to determine if one is newer than the other.
2. I want to convert a file from csv to xls on a computer that doesn't have excel. Only if the statement above is true, the initial xls file was copied already.
3. I want to copy the newly converted xls file to another location
4. If the file is already open it will fail to copy so I want to send out an email alert on success or failure of this operation.

Here is the script that I'm having issues with. The error is "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline." I know it's to do with the email operation but I'm at a loss as to how to write this out manually with all those variables included. There are probably more errors but I'm not seeing them now. Thanks for any help, I appreciate it!

```
$CSV = "C:filename.csv"
$LocalXLS = "C:\filename.xls"
$RemoteXLS = "D:\filename.xls"
$LocalDate = (Get-Item $LocalXLS).LASTWRITETIME
$RemoteDate = (Get-Item $RemoteXLS).LASTWRITETIME
$convert = "D:\CSV Converter\csvcnv.exe"
if ($LocalDate -eq $RemoteDate) {break}
else { 
& $convert $CSV $LocalXLS
$FromAddress = "email@address.com"
$ToAddress = "email@address.com"
$MessageSubject = "vague subject"
$SendingServer = "mail.mail.com"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $FromAddress, $ToAddress, $MessageSubject, $MessageBody
$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $SendingServer
$SendEmailSuccess = $MessageBody = "The copy completed successfully!" | New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient mail.mail.com $SMTPMessage
$RenamedXLS = {$_.BaseName+(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd)+$_.Extension}

Rename-Item -path $RemoteXLS -newname $RenamedXLS -force -erroraction silentlycontinue
If (!$error)
    { $SendEmailSuccess | copy-item $LocalXLS -destination $RemoteXLS -force }
Else
    {$MessageBody = "The copy failed, please make sure the file is closed." | $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish on this line: $SendEmailSuccess = $MessageBody = "The copy completed successfully!" | New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient mail.mail.com $SMTPMessage But I imagine that it is the culprit of the error.

Comment: @meep - don't edit out the content. There is not point in having your question at all then. This will be useful for future visitors even though you have figured it out. Append your edits.

Answer (score 13):

You get this error when you are trying to execute an independent block of code from within a pipeline chain.

Just as a different example, imagine this code using jQuery:

```
$("div").not(".main").console.log(this)
```

Each dot (`.`) will chain the array into the next function.  In the above function this breaks with `console` because it's not meant to have any values piped in.  If we want to break from our chaining to execute some code (perhaps on objects in the chain - we can do so with `each` like this:

```
$("div").not(".main").each(function() {console.log(this)})
```

The solution is powershell is identical.  If you want to run a script against each item in your chain individually, you can use [`ForEach-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849731.aspx) or it's alias (`%`).

Imagine you have the following function in Powershell:

```
$settings | ?{$_.Key -eq 'Environment' } | $_.Value = "Prod"
```

The last line cannot be executed because it is a script, but [we can fix that with ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25081472/1366033) like this:

```
$settings | ?{$_.Key -eq 'Environment' } | %{ $_.Value = "Prod" }
```

Answer (score 5):

This error basically happens when you use an expression on the receiving side of the pipeline when it cannot receive the objects from the pipeline.

You would get the error if you do something like this:

```
$a="test" | $a
```

or even this:

```
"test" | $a
```

I don't know why are trying to pipe everywhere. I would recommend you to learn basics about Powershell pipelining. You are approaching it wrong. Also, I think you can refer to the link below to see how to send mail, should be straight forward without the complications that you have added with the pipes : http://www.searchmarked.com/windows/how-to-send-an-email-using-a-windows-powershell-script.php

Comment: I love the pipe, but I find it to be over used. Especially inside scripts. I use the pipe all the time at a command prompt, but I rarely use it in a script.

Comment: @EBGreen - I think the real problem is only when you don't really understand what's happening. For example, you can use `$a | write-host` rather than `write-host $a`. And yeah, sometimes it is overused. Nice to write one-liners, but hard to maintain scripts that other have to read and maintain.

Comment: Yup even when they are used completely right in a script I just see it as a matter of good habits (for myself anyway) to go ahead and make as much explicit as possible in a script. This means less piping and explicit cmdlet names rather than aliases.

Comment: I was trying to get it to send different messages based on the error result. What you showed me in that script is something I've already tried to do. The result is the same when I put that to send the email. Please explain how I would get it to send different messages based on different responses.