# Basic PowerShell Script Issue: "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline"

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to write a simple script that reads a file, locates a string, replaces the string with another string, and stores all new file contents (with replaced string), in a new file. Here is what I'm using:

```
(Get-Content C:\file1.txt) | {$_ -replace "this:text", "withthis:text"} | Set-Content C:\file2.txt
```

The error I'm receiving is: "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline"

I'm pretty sure this is because of the colon ":" character being in both the string I'm locating and replacing it with. I've tried escaping the colon character with "\" and "`" characters, but I'm receiving the same errors. Does anyone know what's wrong with this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is the second element in your pipeline.

```
{$_ -replace "this:text", "withthis:text"}
```

This is a scriptblock (i.e. a piece of code).  If you want to apply a scriptblock to all of the incoming items on a pipeline you can use the `foreach-object` cmdlet like this:

```
(Get-Content C:\file1.txt) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "this:text", "withthis:text"} | Set-Content C:\file2.txt
```

@shagun is using the `%` alias for the `foreach-object` cmdlet, so that code looks correct as well.

Comment: Just FYI: if you would have script block that is pipeline-ready on it's own (e.g. `{ process { $_ * 2 }}`) you could just use call operator (`&`): `1, 2, 3 | & { process { $_ * 2 }}`

Comment: To add to @BartekB's note, if you have a scriptblock with a `ValueFromPipeline` parameter, like `param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$x)`, `$x` will also correctly receive each element when the scriptblock is used as the argument of `&` in a pipeline. This might be a useful way to write the scriptblock because then you can either call it in a pipeline or by itself, which is tricky if you make it use `$_`.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is because after first pipe you are not processing each result. so the right one will be according to me :

```
(Get-Content C:\file1.txt) | %{$_ -replace "this:text", "withthis:text"} | Set-Content C:\file2.txt
```