# Copy-Item Remotely from list of servers in CSV

Tags: powershell

Pardon if this is redundant but I can't seem to get this to work.

```
    Import-CSV C:\Scripts\VMLIST.csv | ForEach {
$vm = $_.vmname 
Copy-Item -Path C:\PSWindowsUpdate\ -Destination \\$vm\C$\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate\
Copy-Item -Path C:\PSWindowsUpdate\* -Destination \\$vm\C$\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate\
}
```

The problem is with the $vm variable. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong with syntax. I've tried '', "", brackets. My column is correctly titled and I've used the CSV for snapshots so I know that isn't the problem.

The output says Network Path is Not Found. So does that mean it is not possible?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7151463/3775798) help at all, or perhaps [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25078049/3775798)? The exact code is different, but the error you mention seems to be a common one.

Comment: Thank You, I attempted to fix that error. I guess I was more concerned with the getting the vmname variable into my network path.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have to escapse the `$` sign when using ..\C$\.. . Maybe PowerShell tries to replace "$\" through a variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is the second pipeline command `$vm = $_.vmname`. This is not allowed to be there like it is.

But it would work if you include it in your `ForEach-Object` statement:

```
Import-CSV C:\Scripts\VMLIST.csv | ForEach {
$vm = $_.vmname
Copy-Item -Path C:\PSWindowsUpdate\ -Destination "\\$vm\C$\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate\"
Copy-Item -Path C:\PSWindowsUpdate\* -Destination "\\$vm\C$\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate\"
}
```

It's more readable, if you use the switch `-recurse` in your copy-statement too:

```
Import-CSV C:\Scripts\VMLIST.csv | ForEach {
$vm = $_.vmname
Copy-Item -Path C:\PSWindowsUpdate\ -Destination "\\$vm\C$\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate\" -rec
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just changed my code around to get to the issue I was concerned with. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear now, but it still says network path not found.

Comment: Does it work, if you wrap the `Destination` in double quotes? (`"`)

Comment: No, unfortunately. It doesn't seem to recognize the variable in the path, in the error output it is showing it as \\$vm\C$...

Comment: All parts but CSV path was copied from your code, this is the output: 
        Copy-Item : The network path was not found.
At line:3 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path C:\PSWindowsUpdate\ -Destination "\\$vm\C$\Windows\System32\Wind ...

Comment: So, either the trailing backslash at `-path C:\PSWindowsUpdate\` is messing it up, or your vm is just not avaiable.

Comment: Well thanks for helping. I ended up running the Copy-Item command manually entering each of the servers manually. Took a while, but sometimes that happens.